# Change user voice

Tags: discord.js, voice

How can I change the user's voice in real time?
Or, in case it isn't possible, how can I get the user's voice, modify it and let the bot speak it?

Comment: Usually we help with issues, not figure out how to make a full feature. You might want to look for voice changer libraries and then try them out and finally route the voice of that user through the voice changer and then make the bot send it

Comment: So far, I couldn't even figure out how to get the bot to speak what I say. The only clue I have is it to use a [VoiceBroadcast](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceBroadcast)

Comment: Perhaps use [this](https://gist.github.com/eslachance/fb70fc036183b7974d3b9191601846ba) as a start. In a nutshell (to my knowledge), it will 'listen' to the user provided and output what they said into a file, which you can then use with the [VoiceBroadcast](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceBroadcast) feature of Discord.js.

Comment: I stumbled upon this Gist code. This isn't reliable for 2 reasons: 1. If the user speaks, the bot will output his voice, i.e. an echo will be heard. 2. Since an echo will be heard, the user will have to be muted, which will result in the bot for being unable to pick the voice, which will make it useless